# GridView_RowUpdating event not firing in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help as I am not able to find the solution to an issue. I have gone through many solutions on Stackoverflow as well as Microsoft Sites but am not able to find the issue.

I have a Gridview in VS2005 but the rowupdating evvent is not firing when I clock on the Update button in the GridView.

Below is the .aspx code. Can anyone please help me understand what have I missed here.

```
asp:GridView ID="dbgrdReport" 
CellPadding="4" 
EnableTheming="True"  
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
SkinID="GridFormat" 
ShowFooter="True" 
AllowSorting="True" 
runat="server" 
OnSorting="dbgrdReport_Sorting"
OnRowEditing="dbgrdReport_RowEditing" 
OnRowUpdating="dbgrdReport_RowUpdating" 
OnRowCancelingEdit="dbgrdReport_RowCanceling" 
OnRowDeleting="dbgrdReport_RowDeleting">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added correct property `OnRowUpdating="dbgrdReport_RowUpdating"` to GridView.

Then, there are many things that you have to check:

- In *Properties Box* `-->` <kbd>Events</kbd> `-->` <kbd>OnRowUpdating</kbd> implemented.
- All controls in your GridView haven't same ID.
- Set `AutoGenerateEditButton="False"`.
- Use the code below to add the "Edit" button field to your GridView code as follow:

  ```
   <asp:commandfield showeditbutton="true" causesvalidation="false" headertext="Edit"/>
  ```
- Set the GridView `EnableViewState` property to true.
- Bind your GridView in `if(!IsPostBack)` instead of PostBack in `Page_Load` method.
  -